# python: re.sub's replace function doesn't accept extra arguments - how to avoid global variable?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm trying to increment all timestamps (of the form 'HH:MM:SS') in a text file by a number of seconds specified by a command-line parameter to my program.

Here's a simplified version of my effort so far:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_diff = timedelta(seconds=10)

def replace_time(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1) not in [None, '']:
       return (datetime.strptime(matchobj.group(1), "%H:%M:%S") + time_diff).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print re.sub('(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', replace_time, "01:27:55")
```

This works fine: the result of running this is `01:28:05` which is just what I want.

However, I've heard that I should use global variables as less as possible. So I was wondering if there's a simple way to pass `time_diff` as an argument to `replace_time` instead of using a global variable.

I tried the obvious, but it failed:

```
def replace_time(matchobj, time_diff):
    if matchobj.group(1) not in [None, '']:
       return (datetime.strptime(matchobj.group(1), "%H:%M:%S") + time_diff).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

time_diff = timedelta(seconds=10)
print re.sub('(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', replace_time(matchobj, time_diff), "01:27:55")
```

with this error: `NameError: name 'matchobj' is not defined`, so I can't pass matchobj directly.

I've looked at the [standard re page](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and [standard re howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html), but can't find the information I need over there. How can I avoid using a global variable here? Can I somehow pass an extra argument to the `replace_time` function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can wrap a function in a closure like this:

```
def increment_by(time_diff):
    def replace_time(matchobj):
        if matchobj.group(1) not in [None, '']:
            return (datetime.strptime(matchobj.group(1), "%H:%M:%S") + time_diff).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return replace_time

time_diff = timedelta(seconds=10)
print re.sub('(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', increment_by(time_diff), "01:27:55")
```

Or you can use a `partial` from stdlib like this:

```
from functools import partial

def replace_time(time_diff, matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1) not in [None, '']:
        return (datetime.strptime(matchobj.group(1), "%H:%M:%S") + time_diff).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

time_diff = timedelta(seconds=10)
print re.sub('(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', partial(replace_time, time_diff), "01:27:55")
```

Comment: Great! I just tried both approaches and they work fine, but I don't yet understand how either does its magic. Now I have to choose between 3 options: (a) use a closure, (b) use a partial, or (c) continue to use the global, as suggested by David Heffernan. What are the trade-offs of each option, and how should I decide?

Comment: Well, actually options (a) and (b) are the same, since `partial` does almost what my `increment_by` does here, only it's more generic. In fact, I've written it for you to understand the idea better. As for (b) vs. (c) — well, I'd prefer the (b) in most cases. First, global state is always a source of nasty bugs. Second, in Python global vars lookups are more expensive.

Comment: Awesome. I've decided to avoid the global option based on your and David Heffernan's advice. I've decided to take the (b) route as it makes the most sense to me, is easier for me to grasp and use, and solves my problem rather elegantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your current approach. `time_diff` is written to once only and then all future accesses are reads. It effect it is a module wide constant.

You run into problems with shared global state when you have multiple threads accessing an object and at least one of the threads is writing. That's not happening here and you have nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks. I've often seen advice to avoid global variables like the plague not just in Python, but as a general programming practice. That's why I wanted to find an alternative to my global var usage. So is it okay to have global variables if I'm not doing multi-threading?

Also, in this particular case, if I were later to make a module out of my code and import it in other programs, would the global variable still be okay, or could it cause problems? 

I'm just trying to understand the guidelines of when it's okay to have globals.

Comment: If you are going to expose this as a module you'd wrap it up in a function and probably use the closure approach.